# Android - Glide 4.0.0-RC0: how to set tint color for ImageView after successfully loading SVG

Tags: android, svg, android-glide, tint

I followed this sample: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg

After successfully loading SVG file with Glide 4.0.0-RC0, i want to set tint color for ImageView, but setColorFilter NOT WORKING

My source:

```
package com.example.quangson.glidesvg;

import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder;
import com.example.quangson.glidesvg.glide.GlideApp;
import com.example.quangson.glidesvg.glide.SvgSoftwareLayerSetter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SVGActivity";
    private ImageView imageViewSVG;
    private ImageView imageViewPNG;
    private RequestBuilder<PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewSVG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.svg_image_view1);
        imageViewPNG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.svg_image_view2);

        imageViewPNG.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_mylogo);

        requestBuilder = GlideApp.with(this)
                .as(PictureDrawable.class)
                .error(R.drawable.image_error)
                .transition(withCrossFade())
                .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/"  + R.raw.android_toy_h);
        requestBuilder.load(uri).into(imageViewSVG);

        imageViewSVG.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        imageViewPNG.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}
```

In my source:

I loaded PNG image (from res/drawable) into imageViewPNG and setColorFilter for imageViewPNG ⇒ WORKING

I loaded SVG image (from res/raw) into imageViewSVG and setColorFilter for imageViewSVG ⇒ NOT WORKING (Loaded SVG file successfully but can't setColorFilter)

Please help me set tint color for imageViewSVG.

---

I tried edit like below code to making SvgDrawableTranscoder that generates a BitmapDrawable (and will setColorFilter after that), but it's not working, help me?

```
package com.sonzero.chibiz.glide;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable;

import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.SimpleResource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.transcode.ResourceTranscoder;
import com.caverock.androidsvg.SVG;

/**
 * Convert the {@link SVG}'s internal representation to an Android-compatible one
 * ({@link Picture}).
 */
public class SvgDrawableTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<SVG, BitmapDrawable> {
    @Override
    public Resource<BitmapDrawable> transcode(Resource<SVG> toTranscode) {
        SVG svg = toTranscode.get();
        Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
        PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
        Bitmap bitmap = asBitmap(drawable);
        BitmapDrawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        return new SimpleResource<BitmapDrawable>(mDrawable);
    }

    public Bitmap asBitmap(PictureDrawable pd) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pd.getIntrinsicWidth(),pd.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like its [not implemented](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=setColorFilter&type=) raise an issue on github.

Comment: It just support Drawable or GifDrawable, NOT SVG. please help

Comment: Help how? You need someone to implement this if you wish to continue to use this library. You'll likely need to do it yourself or pay someone else to do it.

Comment: Do you know any other solution that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

The Glide SVG loader produces a `PictureDrawable`.  Last I checked, PictureDrawables do not support the `setColorFilter()` method.

What you could try is making your own version of the `SvgDrawableTranscoder` that generates a `BitmapDrawable` instead and draws into that using AndroidSVG's `renderToCanvas()` method.

**Update**

AndroidSVG 1.4+ now supports passing extra CSS at render time.  Create a `RenderOptions` object and supply some CSS rules using `.css()`. You can then pass that `RenderOptions` object to `renderToPicture()` in your `SvgDrawableTranscoder`.

```
RenderOptions  renderOptions = RenderOptions.create().css("path { fill: red; }");
Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture(renderOptions);
...etc...
```

[RenderOptions documentation](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/doc/index.html)

Comment: I tried edit like below code, but it's not working, can you help me?

Comment: public class SvgDrawableTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<SVG, BitmapDrawable> {
    @Override
    public Resource<BitmapDrawable> transcode(Resource<SVG> toTranscode) {
        SVG svg = toTranscode.get();
        Picture picture = svg.renderToPicture();
        PictureDrawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(picture);
        Bitmap bitmap = asBitmap(drawable);
        BitmapDrawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        return new SimpleResource<BitmapDrawable>(mDrawable);
    }
}

Comment: public Bitmap asBitmap(PictureDrawable pd) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pd.getIntrinsicWidth(),pd.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
    }

Comment: I can't read this code. Please add an "Update" section to your question, or ask a new question.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: after i tried to change SvgDrawableTranscoder, i can't load SVG file to ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Here my approach working fine

**Step-1** Create method for updating imageview color

```
fun ImageView.paintColor(colorString: String) {
    val paint = Paint()
    val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.parseColor(colorString), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    paint.colorFilter = colorFilter
    setLayerPaint(paint)
}
```

**Step-2**  simple call this function where you wants to update this image color

```
 yourImageView.paintColor("#ff0000")
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it paints the imageview black regardless of the color provided.